# Accessing top-level collection in Firebase Firestore

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm currently developing a web app in angular 5 with firebase. Anyway I'm using angular/firestore2 for that purpose.

The problem I have is that I cannot access my top-level collection. My structure is something like

Collection(top level collection ['events']) -> Docs(related to userId) -> Collection -> Docs

If I'm trying to access top level within

`return this.db.collection('events').valueChanges();`

It returns empty array, although there are documents inside that collection. Anyway If I make new custom collection like:

Collection (top level collection ['tests']) -> Docs

and I try to access that collection within

`return this.db.collection('tests').valueChanges();`

It returns the array with the docs inside.. I'm really confused and would appreciate any help..

I'm using https://github.com/angular/angularfire2 for firestore/storage connections.

Comment: Where do you make the changes you want to detect? In the document directly under the events collection or in the sub-collection?

Comment: @RenaudTarnec it depends. If the user doesn't have any posted events, when creating his first event, I'm creating a document in the top level collection with user ID just for reference, after that when always creating some new event , adding new documents in the sub-collection.

Comment: @RenaudTarnec after that I'll create edit functionality for the events where I'll reference the events based on userId so Collection(events) -> Doc(userId) -> Collections( weekdayEvents) -> Docs ( .update(the new object) )

Answer (score 1):

I am not 100% sure of what follows since I don't use angular/firestore2 but it says in the [documentation](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/firestore/collections.md) that "The AngularFirestoreCollection service is a wrapper around the native Firestore SDK's `CollectionReference` and `Query` types".

Queries in Firestore are **shallow queries**, therefore when you make a modification in a document under a sub-collection, the listener declared at the collection's parent document will not be fired.

What is explained in the "standard" Javascript SDK [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen) for the `onSnapshot()` method is similar: "You can listen to **a** document with the `onSnapshot()` method." It does not include changes in the document's sub-collections.